# "TypeError: r is null" when creating d3 pie chart

Tags: d3.js, svg, typeerror, pie-chart

I'm using d3 v4.  I'm trying to create a simple pie chart using the below code

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", 
                 "#8a89a6", 
                 "#7b6888", 
                 "#6b486b", 
                 "#a05d56", 
                 "#d0743c", 
                 "#ff8c00",
                 "#e34d01",
                 "#ccff05",
                 "#3e7eca",
                 "#aa0092",
                 "#b32e4f"]);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.market_cap; });

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var csvData = "currency,market_cap";
csvData += "Ethereum,36536577384"; 
csvData += "Ripple,9562570727"; 
csvData += "Bitcoin Cash,10407237657"; 
csvData += "Litecoin,4537371026"; 
csvData += "NEM,2962953000"; 
csvData += "Dash,2903791940"; 
csvData += "IOTA,2289563023"; 
csvData += "Ethereum Classic,1955610226"; 
csvData += "NEO,1599450000"; 
csvData += "Monero,2170429814"; 
csvData += "Stratis,703350671"; 
csvData += "Bitcoin,80149315484"; 
var data = d3.csvParse(csvData);
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.market_cap = +d.market_cap;
  return d;
});


  var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  arc.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.currency); });

  arc.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.currency; });
```

I created a demo here -- https://jsfiddle.net/rgw12x8d/12/ .  However, upon running the code, it results in a cryptic

```
TypeError: r is null
```

What does this mean, but more importantly, how do I resolve it?

Comment: Very odd, I got your data to draw locally with a line break (`\n`) on each row in the faux csv, but the fiddle error comes from the first couple lines, d3.select() is not selecting anything here for some reason, and the script fails in trying to get width: https://jsfiddle.net/v0L9vajy/

Comment: When substituting the non-minimized version of d3 v4, `r is null` is replaced with `node is null` as the error, slightly less cryptic, but no less puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, `d3.select` is not selecting anything because you had `load type: no wrap - in head`, when it should be `load type: no wrap - in body`.

Besides that, the way you're "faking" your CSV is wrong. You are concatenating strings, but adding no line break to them. A simpler alternative is just using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var csvData = `currency,market_cap
Ethereum,36536577384
Ripple,9562570727
Bitcoin Cash,10407237657
Litecoin,4537371026
NEM,2962953000
Dash,2903791940
IOTA,2289563023
Ethereum Classic,1955610226
NEO,1599450000
Monero,2170429814
Stratis,703350671
Bitcoin,80149315484`;
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n3xrbnzj/

Comment: Ah, I was stumped on the `d3.select` portion, nice answer